# Find exact characters in string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings like below

```
M10 end 
start M11
M1
M1 start
M n1
end M1
```

What I am trying to achieve is get the result having only "**M1**" using regex.

This is my current code

```
Regex r = new Regex("^M1$|M1$");
```

The output looks like below which is missing string "M1 start"

```
M1
end M1
```

Comment: Would you want it to match `start M1 end` too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex("^.*\\bM1\\b.*$");
```

This should do it for you.See demo.Here `\b` is word boundary which will match only `M1` and not `M10`.

> \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/113

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want not to overuse Regex, you can use

```
target="M1";
if( underTest.IndexOf(target) == 0 && underTest.Lenght == target.Lenght)
{
 ....
}
```

using a `StringReader` to split each line.