# Looping through datatable using regex to find exact string is slow

Tags: c#, regex, linq, datatable

I have to match the exact string from the datatable and calculate the voting count for each candidate. I have a List of votingId for the candidates and I match the votingId using regex with datatble using linq. But, looping through each row of datatable to find match is extremely slow because I have to search 20 times as there are 20 candidates. So if there are 100 rows then it will loop for 2000 times.

Below is my current code for reference

```
List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20" };

for (int i = 0; <= votingcodes.Count ; i++)
{
   foreach (DataRow dr in dtFilter.Rows)
   {
     dr["FMSG_IN"] = dr["FMSG_IN"].ToString().ToUpper();
     Regex r = new Regex("^.*\\b" + votingcodes[i] + "\\b.*$");
     DataView dv = (from t in dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("FMSG_IN") ??"") select t).AsDataView();
   }
}
```

Within the loop I am also calculating votes for each candidate and creating a datatable to bind it to a grid.

Solution - Well, because of my stupidity I forgot to remove the foreach loop on dtfilter datatable which is not required because I am getting filtered data in dataview and with that view I can do all sort of manipulations.

Below if the working code as per my question.

```
List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20" };

for (int i = 0; < votingcodes.Count ; i++)
{
     Regex r = new Regex("^.*\\b" + votingcodes[i] + "\\b.*$");
     DataView dv = (from t in dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("FMSG_IN") ??"") select t).AsDataView();

}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to find if a string doesnt contain `"\\b" + votingcodes[i] + "\\b"`? Have you tried testing this without regex?

Comment: I am trying to find a matching string based on list. Yes, I have tried testing it without regex. I used rowfilter like expression but I never got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach (DataRow dr in dtFilter.Rows)` is redundant, remove it. You may also use `Regex.Escape(votingcodes[i])` to make sure special chars are escaped and use unambigupus word boundaries, `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)`. I noticed a typo in your `for` loop, fixed.

Also, there is no point in using `.*` to match the whole  string since `Regex.IsMatch` can find partial matches. It will also speed up the code execution.

```
List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20" };

foreach (var votingcode in votingcodes)
{
     Regex r = new Regex($@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(votingcode)}(?!\w)");
     DataView dv = (from t in dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("FMSG_IN") ??"") select t).AsDataView();

}
```

Comment: And replace the for loop with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
            List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20" };
            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            

            List<DataRow> filterRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x =>  votingcodes.Contains(x.Field<string>("FMSG_IN"))).ToList();
​
```

Comment: I cannot use the contains method because FMSG_IN will have all kinds of strings in it and I have to take the exact string. My previous question will help you understand more about what I am talking about. Here is the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674300/find-exact-characters-in-string-using-regex/29674318#29674318

Answer (score 0):

Some text files just have to be parsed in sequential order reading line by line.  I have parsed very complicated text files in the last 40 years and have a vast amount of experience.  The sample data in your last posting is just sample lines of data and doesn't actually show the structure of the data file. The data doesn't seem to be accurate since you have both "end M10" and "m1 end".  Real data is very rarely inconsistent having the order of the string backwards like that.  I can help solve this issue if I have enough real sample data.